# dynamic viscosity in the minute scale

Tags: unit-conversion

The dynamic viscosity of air is $1.78\cdot 10^{-5}Pas = 1.78\cdot 10^{-5}\frac{kg}{ms}$. How do I convert this to the minute scale? I see a reason for multiplying the value with 60 (because of the $\frac{kg}{ms}$) or dividing it by 60 (because of the $Pa s$).

Background: I need the value in a numerical CFD simulation, where I have all my timesteps in the minute scale.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do a straight up unit conversion, do the proper steps for dimensional analysis:

$$
1.78\times 10^{-5}\frac{kg}{m\dot\ sec} * \frac{60\ sec}{1\ min} = (1.78 \times 10^{-5}) * 60 \frac{kg}{m\dot\ min} 
$$

Then the seconds cancel and you're left with the term on the "minute scale", if this is what you mean.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. But if you do the same thing with the Pascal second unit, you get another value. Which way is the one to choose? And why?

Comment: I don't understand - the Pascal-second unit is completely equivalent to kg/ms, so you shouldn't have to choose anything to do the conversion.

Comment: yes. But when I change the Pascal-second into Pascal-minute, I get another value. Or am I wrong here?